# Bootstrap floating side bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float, sidebar

https://www.bootply.com/101100#

I have found this and Im using the code for the floating side bar on my website. However, I want to move the sidebar a bit more left. I cant seem to find the CSS for it or maybe i was looking in all wrong. I would appreciate your help. I've tried changing some codes using dev tools(inspect button on browser)

And also, is there a way to make this behave properly on mobile?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The sidebar is structured as the contents of a column in that example. It's aligned to the left edge of the first column, which is aligned with the left side of the row, and ultimately the left side of the container. This is standard Bootstrap structure. You might consider using `container-fluid` to expand the entire layout of your page closer to the edges of the viewport.

To retain the existing page width, you could pull the sidebar over with negative margin:

```
.sidebar-nav-fixed {
    margin-left: -30px;
}
```

This shifts the sidebar from its normal layout in the grid.

You could also set it with respect to the viewport:

```
.sidebar-nav-fixed {
    left: 20px;
}
```

These approaches may have undesirable side effects for smaller screens or mobile layout, however. It's better to use a standard layout grid pattern.